# Water effect "on android" for a 2D game. Where to start?

Tags: android, game-physics, 2d-games

I wanna to add some water effects in my android 2D game to give the impression that objects are under water and the water becomes higher and higher. Is there a way to do this programmatically. May be someone can give me please some code suggestions or can say where can I find something to get started. I like to do things programmatically. One time I saw a fire effect artificial done with code. Is the same possible in the water case ?

Comment: Possibly useful thread on sister site: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/8727/how-to-add-water-effect-to-an-image.  Personally I'd expect to use GL shaders for this.

Comment: Think the most relevant thing you need to tell us is what technology you are going to use: one of the GL specifications for android? or perhaps android own 2D graphics technology?

Comment: Are you looking for the “reflection in water” effect, or more of a “looking through water distortion/diffraction,” or simply “some blue watery stuff tints the things behind it?” All of these can be done fairly fast in real time…

Comment: And be specific: what kind of water effect do you refer to? Rising water level including mirror effect on top? or water drops on the "screen"...

Comment: I'm sorry..Possible I would like to use my algorithm no GL library..the effect should be simple for 2D game. I want distortion/diffraction and tints changes. The point of view is lateral..so I could see the fishes which swim in the water and other stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to have write a gl shader for the water effect.

steps:

- render scene to render target (texture)
- apply shader to render target

There are many different ways to write water type shaders in 2d. Search around for the technique that best suites your needs.

Caveat: Shader only work on devices with programable pipelines (devices that support OpenGL ES  2.0+

Comment: Ok..and without the use of OpenGl ? Is this possible ?

Comment: yes it's possible to do any of these 2d effects in software, however it most likely won't be as fast as using shaders. Basically you'll have to find an algorithm to deform the image and directly manipulate the pixels. Check out this to get an idea (Android Pixel Buffer) http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html

Comment: give example, please