# How this animation called in android?

Tags: android, animation

I don't know if this question is good for this place, but I have no idea how called this animation which looks like something is dropped to water and from this point goes circles which became bigger and bigger like on the lake.

Like on this image
[image]

I can see this effect many time, for example in some phones when the screen is blocked, when we click on the key we get this effect.
So I think this effect has a name in android and I'm so curious about it, because I wanna add it to my app. I would be great for this answer

Comment: That animation is not a part of standard android and I am not aware of any special name. See: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/iVs5CGCD8Tk , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669023/water-effect-on-android-for-a-2d-game-where-to-start , ...

Comment: not rly xD I change it.      @zapl:thx for this links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a  [Riple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ripple_effect) effect, what android version did you see it on?

Comment: the simple version of it, I see on the screen of nexus 10, when It's locked and we push the key image.The simple circles goes from there. It's android 4.3, and this effect i have on my mind, thx a lot